# ¿como cambiar ScrollView-horizontal={true} a false? en react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

He intentado cambiar de true a false en la propiedad "horizontal- scrollview" con `setState` pero no funciona , quiza alguien ya ha intentado.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      estadoimg: false
    };
  }
  onclickicon = () => {
    this.setState({ estadoimg: !this.state.estadoimg });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onclickicon}>
          <Icon name="ios-arrow-dropdown" size={32} color="#4F8EF7" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={() => {
            return this.state.estadoimg;
          }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {imagenes}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo un par de cosas que creo podrían ayudarte.
Primero, en general cuando usas un state dentro de una llamada a `setState`, es mejor pasar una función callback, ya que la actualización de estados sucede de manera asíncrona y no siempre va a ser en el orden que tu esperas. Más info en [la doc. de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

```
  onclickicon = () => {
    this.setState((state, _props) => {
      return { estadoimg: !state.estadoimg };
    });
  };
```

luego puedes pasar la referencia a tu estado directamente, sin necesidad de invocar una función anónima.

```
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={this.state.estadoimg}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
```

Comment: Eres un capito :) , si ha funcionado ,,.. Gracias

Comment: @fhk me alegro. Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, considera [marcarla como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/213), haciendo click en la palomita al costado de mi respuesta. Saludos